# How to crop an image by detecting the edge in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to crop the image by detecting the image edge in flutter. But i am not getting how to do that. I have also tried the package [edge_detection](https://pub.dev/packages/edge_detection/example) but its not working well for the documents. Is there is another method to detect the edge properly and crop that image.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from [edge_detection](https://pub.dev/packages/edge_detection) there is no official library published by [pub_dev](https://pub.dev/) that contains cropping with edge detection.

However, you should check out this [link](https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/tutorials/implementing-edge-detection-in-flutter/2020/1509) which contains the essentials for the implementation in your project.

Answer (score 0):

After declaring edge detection version within your pubspec.yaml file, you can use the following code to detect the edge and crop your photo.

```
  Future edge() async {
    try {
      //Make sure to await the call to detectEdgeFromGallery.
      bool success = await EdgeDetection.detectEdgeFromGallery(_selectedImage!.path,
        androidCropTitle: 'Crop', // use custom localizations for android
        androidCropBlackWhiteTitle: 'Black White',
        androidCropReset: 'Reset',
      );

      print("Success11");
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      print("NoSuccess11");
    }

  }
```